# I have to move an accordion from left to right, how?

Tags: css, layout, accordion, zk

I'm using ZKoss for a web pages and i'm trying to use  for grouping information. The accordion of this tag is on the left and i want to move it to the right.
How?
The CSS doesn't help with tips and i did not found nothing on the web.
My code:

```
<detail open="false">
   <image sclass="myimg" width="20px" height="20px" src="ico1.png" />
   <label value="Product" />
</detail>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @user2622418 Please share code if you can.

Comment: @Paulie_D Here my short code:
<detail open="false">
     <image  sclass="myimg" 
                   width="20px" height="20px"
     src="ico1.png" />
     <label value="Product" />
</detail>
This tag <detail> set an accordion with the button + or - on the left; I want this button on the right, how can I do it?

Comment: Please update your **question** with this code rather than add it to a comment. A demo in JSfiddle would also be useful.

Comment: Do you just want the detail at the end of the row in stead of start of the row?

Comment: context of your detail? inside a listbox, a grid a div? it'll be more helpful to see the entire code..please update your question